# Behaviour of np.where() for 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a numpy 2d array and each array element contains a dictionary.

```
[[{'foo': 1} {'bar': 2, 'xyz': 7} {} {}]
 [{} {'xyz': 7} {'bar': 2} {'foo': 1}]
 [{} {'xyz': 7} {'foo': 1} {'bar': 2}]]
```

I'm trying to return all indices for each row whose dictionary contains a given key.

My current solution looks like this:

```py
indices = []
for row in arr:
  for i in range(len(row)):
    if 'foo' in row[i].keys():
      indices.append(i)
```

and returns

```py
[0, 3, 2]
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to write it also with the use of np.where()

I've found this is almost what I'm looking for

```py
np.where([[['foo' in ele.keys()] for ele in row] for row in arr])
```

but it returns 3 arrays (the middle one is the correct one)

```py
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 3, 2]), array([0, 0, 0]))
```

I don't understand the first and the third array, why are they created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [226]: [[['foo' in ele.keys()] for ele in row] for row in arr]                                    
Out[226]: 
[[[True], [False], [False], [False]],
 [[False], [False], [False], [True]],
 [[False], [False], [True], [False]]]
```

Make that an array, giving a shape (3,4,1).  `where` returns a tuple of arrays, one for each dimension.

Use a grouping () instead of [], gives a 2d array:

```
In [227]: [[('foo' in ele.keys()) for ele in row] for row in arr]                                    
Out[227]: 
[[True, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, True],
 [False, False, True, False]]
```

`frompyfunc` is another way of applying a function to each element of an array.  It tends to be a bit faster than explicit loops (up to 2x), and is especially nice when working with object dtype arrays:

```
In [228]: np.frompyfunc(lambda d: 'foo' in d.keys(),1,1)(arr)                                        
Out[228]: 
array([[True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, True],
       [False, False, True, False]], dtype=object)
In [229]: np.where(_)                                                                                
Out[229]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 3, 2]))
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I understood the part with grouping instead of [] and because this is now a 2-dimensional array, 'where' now returns two arrays. But why array([0, 1, 2]) is still a "valid" solution, I mean on 2nd row the 2nd value is False and not True. I'm sure it is correct but I don't get the point why this is correct.

Comment: The [0,1,2] identifies the row, the [0,3,2] the column.  They work together.  `np.argwhere(...)` shows the same values in a way that might be easier to understand.  In your case you only have one True per row, but `where` can handle 0 or 2 (or more) per row.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. And because of that without grouping, the third value always returns 'array([0, 0, 0])' because of the shape (3,4,1), so the last entry could only consist of zeros. Initially I thought [0,3,2] -> 0 is the first entry so it represents first row and so on... Yeah with more than one True per row, this approach would not work and we would need additional dimensions. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
x = [[{'foo': 1},{'bar': 2, 'xyz': 7},{},{}],
     [{} ,{'xyz': 7} ,{'bar': 2} ,{'foo': 1}],
     [{}, {'xyz': 7}, {'foo': 1}, {'bar': 2}]]

res = [list(map(lambda elem: 'foo' in elem.keys(),item)) for item in x]
print(res)
print(numpy.where(res))
```

output:

```
[[True, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, True],
 [False, False, True, False]]

(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 3, 2], dtype=int64))
```